# How do I include a clickable hyperlink in ASP.NET MVC Core ModelState error message?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, modelstate

In my controller, there are some custom validations. I want to provide a clickable hyperlink in the ModelState error message, that when clicked, will take the user to different page of the same site for further actions. Something like "Error: please click here to fix it". Here is the scaled down version of the controller.

```
public IActionResult LaunchItem()
{      
    var errorMsg = @"Error: Please click <a href=""https://localhost:44316/Controller/Action"" target=""_blank"">here</a> to fix error.";
    ModelState.AddModelError("", errorMsg);
    return View();
}
```

Here is the portion of the view that presents the error message.

```
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
```

I would like the message to show with the "here" being the clickable hyperlink:

```
Error: Please click <here> to fix error
```

Instead, the message include the whole anchor text, like this:

```
Error: Please click <a href="https://localhost:44316/Controller/Action" target="_blank">here</a> to fix error
```

I think this has something to do with encoding but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: why did not you use viewbag ?

Comment: I'm not sure how viewBag will help? Could you elaborate? In the project, the errors are produced by calling to a "Validation" service that goes on to validate against numerous business logics and collect all errors into an array of errors. One of the errors is the one that needs this clickable hyperlink. In the example here I am showing one simple error message as string to cut down a lot of codes.

Comment: `ModelState` doesn't support HTML for error messages: only raw strings (which are HTML-encoded when rendered by `ValidationMessagesFor` and `ValidationSummary`). Hence why you need to pass the HTML you want via `ViewBag` or a strongly-typed `Model` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try as below:

In controller:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");
 ViewBag.FixMessage = String.Format("Please click <a href={0}>Here</a> to fix", "/Home/Index").ToHtmlString();
```

In View:

```
//remove it
@*<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger" ></div>*@

            @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid&& ViewData.ModelState[""]?.Errors.Count>0)
            {
                <div class="text-danger validation-summary-errors">
                    @ViewBag.FixMessage;
                </div>
                
            }
```

Extension :

```
public static class MyExtension
    {
        public static HtmlString ToHtmlString(this String str)
        {
            return new HtmlString(str);
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]